# Creating an array from a get webhook response nested json

Tags: webhooks, zapier

The current Zapier steps i have set up creates a GET request to an external service. that service replies with a list of data that is nested. My end step i need to do is make multiple PUT requests to another API with part of the URL being a value from the response from the GET. There is not a fixed number of id’s/times that it will need to PUT.

Currently if i do it with just the GET then the next step is the PUT it puts all of the values of the ID i need to put at the end of the API url as just a comma separated list. I need them to make separate PUT requests for Each ID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[This shows the response to the GET request (Images shows only the first part. There will are more in the response)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnfSl.png)

[This is the PUT request. It currently puts them as a comma separated list. which causes an error. each of the values needs to process as a separate PUT.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClNXq.png)

​

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider writing your own [code step](https://zapier.com/help/doc/how-get-started-code-zapier) to format the nested data into an array of objects (JSON).  You could then return the data to `output` and achieve the effect you're looking for, where the next Step runs a PUT request for each item in your `output` array.

Here are Zapier's notes on this strategy:

`Setting the output to an array of objects will run the subsequent steps multiple times — once for each object in the array. If Code by Zapier is the Zap's trigger and an empty array is returned, nothing happens. You can think of it like a polling trigger that did not get any results in the HTTP response. This functionality is exclusive to triggers — returning an empty array in a Code by Zapier action does not have the same effect.`